# What are the pros to using "option explict"?

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic

All it really does is make me have to dim each variable, making it compile badly if I forget to dim a variable.

Are there ANY pros to using it?

Comment: A more approriate question would be, are there any cons? Compiler errors and warnings exist for a reason.

Comment: Are you really asking this? **YES**, use option explicit! Every time!

Comment: And Option Explicit is on by default for a good reason, too.

Comment: The irony of Option Explicit and Option Strict is that you have to be a pretty experienced vb programmer to know how to stay out of trouble and debug the inevitable problems when they are turned off.  Once you get experience, you don't want to turn them off anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will prevent some types of mistakes. 
One of the most obvious ones is if you make a typo and spell the variable name incorrectly, it will flag that the mistyped variable doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

> If you do not use the Option Explicit statement, all undeclared
>   variables are of Object type.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f(v=vs.80).aspx

Think about how this will affect the GC, all your value types that should be stored on the thread stack are now stored on the managed heap and subject to garbage collection. This may not sound huge but the GC would have to check if value types have root references as well as all the reference types. It would have a significant perf impact on the GC as all your value types would be getting promoted up the generations 0,1,2 not just referenced types.

Answer (score 1):

I see having to dim each variable as a big pro.  I can't tell you how many times I tried to run down a bug to find out that I incorrectly spelled a variable that would have been found if  "Option Explicit" had been turned on.

P.S.  Always use Option Explicit.